# JAVA EE remember me

Tags: java, cookie, java-ee, jsf

Использую JSF и `j_security_check`, как можно реализовать функциональность remember me? Сейчас я могу добавить в куки `remoteUser` и найти по нему `User`. Из user могу извлечь `login` и `password(hash)`. При использовании `req.login(user.getLogin(), user.getPassword())` получаю `Security Exception`, как понимаю из за `j_security_check`.

Answer (score 2):

Всего-то навсего надо разработать свой механизм аутентификации, который внедряется довольно глубоко в недра сервера приложений, в обработку http-запроса. Стандарт javaee не покрывает этот аспект. Изучайте внутренности конкретного сервера приложений. И в придачу модуль аутентификации уже по стандартам (не помню как называется).
Это если хотите пользоваться всеми сервисами javaee: @RolesAllowed там..., чтобы пользователь и его роли в EJB распознавались...

Если можете без этого обойтись, то можно найти решение на фильтрах. Например Apache Shiro. Но там javaee не действует, там своя реализация секретности, которая с javaee никак не стыкуется.

Есть возможность сделать аутентификацию по-модному, используя отдельный сервер входа (причем единого для всех или только для некоторых приложений).
Keycloak имеет массу возможностей. Remember me даже не главная из них. Есть  реализация механизма аутентификации для серверов Wildfly, так что там работают и стандартные аннотации и EJB. Главное сообразить как туда свою базу пользователей загнать. Это не очень сложно.

Comment: Слушай, а ты не мог бы дельных статеек или материалов по java ee скинуть. Я просто еще junior, многое из того, что ты написал, не понятно. Или оставь какие нибудь контакты, где можно с тобой связаться и ты бы скинул материалы. За ранее спасибо

Comment: Ничего по javaee нет кроме стандартного руководства, которое на сайте oracle. Чего там нет - так это описания структуры готовых файлов: war, ear, пр. описания дескрипторов деплоя. Часто бывает необходимо знать, что-то подкрутить. Надо гуглить. Так же там нет подробного описания всех API. Это знать надо всегда.  Смотреть javadoc по классам javaee, гуглить. Можете посмотреть конкурирующий Spring. Раньше ему не было альтернативы. Но время течёт, всё меняется.